# every finitely generated vector space has a basis. Question about the proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finitely generated vector space over a field $K$. Then $V$ has a basis.

I have a question about the proof we had in lecture.

Proof: $V$ is finitely generated, this means for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it is $\text{span}(\{v_1,..,v_n\})=V$. Now we proof the claim by induction.
$n=0: \checkmark$ 
The claim holds for n-1. We prove now, that the claim holds for $n$:
Let $\text{span}(\{v_1,..,v_n\})=V$ and $B=\{v_1,..,v_n\}$. If $B$ is linear independend, $B$ is a basis of $V$. If $B$ is not linear independend, there is a $i_0\in \{1,..,n\}$ such that $v_{i_0}=\sum\limits_{k=1, k\not= i_0}^n\frac{-\lambda_i}{\lambda_{i_0}}v_i$. Therefore it it $v_{i_0}\in \{v_1,..,v_n\}\setminus \{v_{i_{0}}\}$ wich is a contradiction. So $B$ must be lineary independend and so $B$ is a basis of $V$. Q.E.D.

My Question is about the end of the proof starting from "Therefore it it $v_{i_0}\in \{v_1,..,v_n\}\setminus \{v_{i_{0}}\}$ wich is a contradiction": Is it correct? And is the proof correct? Is it really a contradiction?

Regards

Comment: The language is very loose. If $V$ is finitely generated, then "for $n \in \Bbb N$" we have "$V = \operatorname{span}\big(\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}\big)$" ? Shouldn't we have quantifiers, like "there **is some** $n \in \Bbb N$", and "**for some** $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$"? Without quantifiers, it feels like you're proving every finitely generated vector space has exactly the same basis. Or perhaps that any list of $n$ vectors (for every conceivable $n$) will work as a basis.

Comment: you are right, my english is bad, sorry. I will correct that later.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the right ending should be 
$$
v_{i_{0}} \in \operatorname{span}(\{ v_{1}, \dots, v_{n} \} \setminus \{ v_{i_{0}}\}),
$$
so $V = \operatorname{span}(\{ v_{1}, \dots, v_{n} \} \setminus \{ v_{i_{0}}\})$ is spanned by $n-1$ elements, and you can apply induction.

Comment: Thank you. If I apply induction now, I can say that V has a basis, because V is spanned by n-1 elements, right? Can we say, that $M=(\{v_1,..,v_n\}\setminus \{v_{i_0}\})$ is a basis of $V$? Or could a basis of $V$ have less elements than M and we have to reduce M until we get a maximal linear independent subset of V if we want to receive a basis (i know that it isn't part of the proof)? (If we already would know the definition of "dimension of a vector field", in this case $V$ is $n-1$ dimensional I think)

Comment: forget the last sentence " (If we already would know the definition of "dimension of a vector field", in this case V is n−1 dimensional I think)"

Comment: Yes, proceeding by induction means exactly that, keep discarding elements until you get an independent set of generators.